# How can I use jquery to display a multiline string text in a span?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, multiline, carriage-return

I have to use jquery to take data and display it in a span that will have it show up on multiple lines?

```
var myString = "a\r\nb\r\nc\r\n";
```

and i want it to show up in my page / span as:

a
b
c

instead of:

a b c

Comment: $(div).html("a\r\nb\r\nc\r\n").css("whiteSpace", "pre-wrap")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do a [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

```
myString = myString.replace(/\r\n/g,"<br />");
```

Answer (score 2):

Change `var myString = "a\r\nb\r\nc\r\n";` to

```
var myString = 'a<br />b<br />c';
```